# Vb.net Stringbuilder to replace in large files

Tags: vb.net, ssis

Hi I want to use stringbuilder to replace carriage returns with line feeds and apostrophes anywhere in the file.I am using the VB script component in SSIS and the for each loop so that one file gets passed on to str_SoucePath Variable at one time.
I have many files which have to be run against this script, but i get this Error when i run it against any file. Please tell me what is wrong.

Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation.

Here is my code:

```
    Public Sub Main()
    Dim data As New StringBuilder(Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath").Value.ToString())
    data.Replace(vbCr, vbLf)
    data.Replace("'", "")

    Console.WriteLine(Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath").Value.ToString())
    Console.ReadLine()
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to post the complete exception, including all inner exceptions, not just the Message property of the outermost exception. In particular, using `ex.ToString()` will tell you more about which "exception was thrown by an invocation of an object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 
    Console.WriteLine(Dts.Variables("User::str_SourcePath").Value.ToString())
Try
    Console.WriteLine(data.toString())

Comment: It works when I run it, might need to see some more code since I can only guess what you are feeding it.  Like John Saunders mentioned, you need to capture the actual error that is occurring to begin troubleshooting.  But my example was to pint out that if you want to see the changed you need to use the string builder not the original text.